# When I use Glide for bitmap, after that I have crash when call getContext in another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-glide

The exception I am getting:

> Process: com.pulse.simplechatfb, PID: 27358 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null Context at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:84) at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:620) at com.pulse.simplechatfb.Activities.MapsActivity$1.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:102) at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source) at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java

My code with Glide for loading an image from a URL from Firebase:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(user.getAvatar()).asBitmap().into(new 
SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(70,70) {
```

Comment: I solved the problem, it was that I used the ValueEventListener and did not close it after replace fragment

Comment: Something like this @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(val!=null)
            q.removeEventListener(val);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847987/glide-load-into-simpletargetbitmap-not-honoring-the-specified-width-and-height